# Re-route a subpath of a WordPress site to another WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, url, url-routing

I have two entirely separate WordPress sites, hosted on AWS.

- foo.com
- bar.com

I'm wondering whether it's possible set up **foo.com** so that when I go to the url: f**oo.com/bar/** the contents are served from **bar.com** site.

I'm aware that setting a sub domain such **bar.foo.com** to point to 'bar' site is a much easier option but this is not desirable in this case.

Thanks much.

Comment: Which server do you use?

Comment: @AqibAshef the two sites are on 2 EC2 instances running Ubuntu

Comment: nginx or apache?

Comment: Apache it seemed. I used the Bitnami Wordpress EC2 image on AWS market.

Comment: Do you want the contents of bar.com to still appear to be on the foo.com/bar page (in other words, do you care if the URL changes?)

Comment: I do want the contents of bar.com to still appear to be on the foo.com/bar

Comment: So this is what I understand from this discussion: You have two sites: foo.com and bar.com and they are live independently. Now you want foo.com/bar to be served from bar.com. at the same time you want bar.com to be live independently as well. Am I right?